# Trying to add current_user.admin in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am rolling my own auth (auth from scratch) for a Rails 6 app. Here is the current code I have:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

  def authorize
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not Authorized" if current_user.nil?
  end
  
    #roles will correspond to user types: admin, student, mentor, ect. 0 is most restrictive (student);
    #5 is most powerful (admins)
  def admin
    if current_user.role != 5
        redirect_to welcome_path, alert: "Not Authorized"
    else
        true
    end
  end
```

...and in my controller I have:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[ show edit update ]
  before_action :authorize, only: :index

  def index
    if admin
      @users = User.all
    else
      redirect_to welcome_path, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    end
  end
...
```

My question is about calling `admin` in the index controller. I feel like this should be `current_user.admin` instead. Can I configure the admin method in the application controller to work like this?

Comment: IMO you should add this method to the `User` model and likely add a `?` e.g. `class User < ApplicationRecord; def admin?; role == 5; end; end`. Then you can use as `if current_user.admin?; admin_things; else; non_admin_things; end`

Comment: I agree, I do like that idea. Could I add that as a before action someone how?

Comment: Yes. You could add it to `authorize` or create another before_action if you'd like. That being said I am not sure how far you want to take this. Don't get me wrong I am all for roll your own type functionality, especially from a learning perspective, but if you are going to take this full scale I would recommend at least looking at and authorization library like [`pundit`](https://github.com/varvet/pundit)

Comment: In your model you can add def admin?
    admin
  end . in controller  if @user == current_user || !!@user == current_user.admin?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up going with:

#user.rb

```
  def is_admin?
    role == 5
  end
```

#users_controller.rb

```
  def index
    if current_user.is_admin?
      @users = User.all
    else
      redirect_to welcome_path, notice: "Not Authorized"
    end
  end
```

I agree with what was said in the comments about pundit. However, this is a smallish app with an educational organization so the value of the learning component of not using gems outweighs any scaling issues at the moment.